# Rolling averages with HQL

Tags: sql, hive, amazon-redshift, rolling-computation

This is my first post on SO. So it is entirely possible I maybe violating a lot of posting rules. If that is the case please let me know and I will make sure not to repeat them.

I have been trying to get to a rolling average and absolute number within the same query in Hive and here is what I have. This worked perfectly in Redshift but gave me an error in Hive. Looks like sub queries within select statements are not supported. Wondering if I could get some pointers on how I can modify this query to give me the same results from Hive.

```sql
select 
    a.ds,
    a.traffic_source,
    a.device_type,
    count(distinct a.unique_id) as daily_deduped_visits_human,
    (select
            count(distinct b.unique_id)
     from
            scratch.unique_human_id b
     where
            b.ds >= a.ds - 28
            and b.ds <= a.ds
            and a.traffic_source = b.traffic_source
            and a.device_type = b.device_type
    )/28 as rolling_28_day_average_visits_human
from
    scratch.unique_human_id a
group by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique in your example is called a correlated subquery and tends to be very slow. I recommend using a window function with a range clause.

First, in a subquery, calculate the metric for each day. Then in the main select use window functions to calculate the rolling sum/avg. [See more window function examples in the Redshift docs.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Window_function_examples.html)

```
SELECT a.ds
     , a.traffic_source
     , a.device_type
     , a.daily_deduped_visits_human
     , SUM(a.daily_deduped_visits_human) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY a.traffic_source, a.device_type 
             ORDER BY a.ds 
             ROWS BETWEEN 28 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
            ) AS rolling_28_day_total_visits_human
     , AVG(a.daily_deduped_visits_human) 
       OVER (PARTITION BY a.traffic_source, a.device_type 
             ORDER BY a.ds 
             ROWS BETWEEN 28 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW 
            ) AS rolling_28_day_average_visits_human
FROM (-- First calc the metric
      SELECT a.ds
           , a.traffic_source
           , a.device_type
           , COUNT(DISTINCT a.unique_id) AS daily_deduped_visits_human
      FROM scratch.unique_human_id a
      GROUP BY 1,2,3
      ) a
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
ORDER BY a.traffic_source
     , a.device_type
     , a.ds
;
```

Comment: Thanks so much Joe. Although this isn't exactly what I was looking for, your solution (which I must say is far more elegant and much faster (seconds vs several mins) than what I initially posted) did give me an idea which I am going to try out today and see how it pans out. Will post my findings here with what I find. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped.